# Node class constructor implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I currently have this code for my node class which stores two names, an ID number, and has a Next ability:

```
class Node{
public:
  char LastName[20] ;
  char FirstName[20] ;
  int IDnumber ;
  Node *Next ;

 Node();
 void printNode();
};
```

This is the constructor I am using to initialize the node variables from the keyboard:

```
Node::Node(){

cout << "Enter ID number: " << endl;
cin >> IDnumber;
cout << "Enter last name: " << endl;
cin >> LastName;
cout << "Enter first name: " << endl;
cin >> FirstName;
Next=NULL;
}

void Node::printNode(){
cout << "ID number: " << IDnumber << endl;
cout << "Last name: "  << LastName <<endl;
cout << "First name: "  << FirstName << endl;
}
```

The problem I am having is that whenever i call the printNode() function later in my code, my code fails to execute the first line of the printNode() function. (unhandled exception) I also fail to execute this code when I attempt to call node->Next with my separate linkedlist class.  This leads me to believe that I am not constructing the node correctly. any ideas on what could be wrong in my code?

The linked list is a separate class that uses the node class I posted above.

```
class LinkedList{

private:
Node* list;
Node* createNode();
Node* searchLocation(int);

public:

LinkedList();
~LinkedList();

void InsertNode();
void SearchNode();
void PrintList();
void DeleteNode(int);

};


LinkedList::LinkedList(){
Node* list = NULL;
}

Node* LinkedList::createNode(){
Node *NewNode = new Node();
return NewNode;
}

void LinkedList::InsertNode(){
Node* insert = createNode();
if (list == NULL){
    list = insert;}}

void LinkedList::PrintList(){
Node* temp = list;
while (temp != NULL){
temp->printNode();
temp = temp->Next;
}
}
```

the PrintList() function of my LinkedList class fails when list->printNode() (there is a break at the cout << IDnumber line) and also fails at the list = list->Next line.

```
int main(){

int num = 0;
    LinkedList list;

  int menu=0;
  while(menu != 5){

  cout << endl << "Choose a menu option." <<endl
   << "1. Insert node " << endl << "2. Delete node " << endl
   << "3. Print list" << endl << "4. Search a node & print info" << endl
   << "5. Quit program  " << endl;


  cin >>  menu;
   menu = validate(menu);

 switch(menu){
 case 1: 
     list.InsertNode();

 break;

case 3: 
    list.PrintList();

 break;
 }}

return 0;

  }
```

Comment: please paste also how you create Node object and how you use it later

Comment: alrighty, i posted it

Comment: Your `PrintList` function trashes the only pointer you have to your list, is that really what you want?

Comment: no, I suppose I should create a temporary pointer. I went ahead and edited that in.

Comment: can you paste main() ?

Comment: Your `LinkedList` constructor sets a local variable called `list` to NULL, but this isn't the `list` in the actual class - meaning your list pointer starts out uninitialized. Also your `InsertNode` function doesn't handle the case where `list` isn't NULL, meaning no additional nodes ever get linked in.

Comment: yes, but he still should print fine just a single node

Comment: I went ahead and pasted my main function. it pretty much just calls the .insertNode and .printList functions.

Comment: should I be setting list to something other than null in the constructor? I should be saving in a node with the insert function before i would call the list variable

Comment: You're not setting `LinkedList::list` to null in the constructor, that's the point. Look again at your function.

Comment: I see. So basically I should be getting rid of the Node* before i set list to null, because otherwise I am creating a new variable?

Answer (score 1):

you have few errors in your code. most important you refer to local `list` pointer which is always `NULL`, when you should refer to some common `Node`, i.e. static variable.

here you can find working solution, please add body for correct list deallocation

```
~LinkedList(){}
```

and you are OK:

LinkedList:

```
class LinkedList{

private:
static Node* list;
Node* createNode();
Node* searchLocation(int);

public:
LinkedList();
~LinkedList(){}
void InsertNode();
void SearchNode();
void PrintList();
void DeleteNode(int);
};

Node* LinkedList::list = NULL;
                 ^
     don't foget to initialize pointer to static object

LinkedList::LinkedList(){
Node* list = NULL;
}

Node* LinkedList::createNode(){
Node *NewNode = new Node();
return NewNode;
}

void LinkedList::InsertNode(){
Node* insert = createNode();
if(list==NULL)list=insert;
else
    list->Next = insert;
}

void LinkedList::PrintList(){
Node* temp = list;
while (temp != NULL){
temp->printNode();
temp = temp->Next;
}
}
```

and main:

```
int main(){

int num = 0;
   LinkedList list;

   cout << endl << "Choose a menu option." <<endl
   << "1. Insert node " << endl << "2. Delete node " << endl
   << "3. Print list" << endl << "4. Search a node & print info" << endl
   << "5. Quit program  " << endl;

   list.InsertNode();
   list.InsertNode();

   list.PrintList();

return 0;

}
```

output:
Choose a menu option.
1. Insert node 
2. Delete node 
3. Print list
4. Search a node & print info
5. Quit program
Enter ID number: 
8
Enter last name: 
i
Enter first name: 
j
Enter ID number: 
9
Enter last name: 
k
Enter first name: 
l

ID number: 8

Last name: i

First name: j

ID number: 9

Last name: k

First name: l

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 14s)

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `nullptr`?